# Android Actionbar tabs Navigation

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-navigation

I am a beginner in android. I have created `Tabs` using `ActionBar` tabs. Now I want to implement, when the user in in first tab and clicks back `Button` activity should close or when the user is in second tab, he clicks the backbutton the app should show the first tab, which will make it as the home tab. I tried using `popupbackstack()` but it always closes the activity no matter what tab i am in.
please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be record the tab state (i.e., which tab is showing) in the host activity, and override the `onBackPressed()` method to do what you want.

Some tips:

1. remember to save the state(override the `onSavedInstanceState()` and save the tab state) to make you activity works right after restore from `onPause()`.
2. read about android's recommended navigation style [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html). What you designed is a little bit different from what android suggests.